# Variation on the definition of the uniform distribution mod 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

A sequence $x_{n}$ is said to be uniformly distributed mod 1 if $\forall a,b$ with $0\leq a<b<1$, 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}|\lbrace j=1,...,n :\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|=(b-a).$$ 
(here $\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace$ is the fractional part of $x_{j}$).
But what about the following:
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{m}|\lbrace j=n,...,n+m :\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|=(b-a),$$
when $n$ is a function of $m$. Does the former imply the latter?

In particular, I'm asking this in order to obtain the following bound:
$$|\lbrace j=n,...,n+m :\lbrace f(j)\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|\ll (b-a)m,$$
with $f(x)$ a polynomial with at least one irrational coefficient and $n=m^{3}$.
A sort of short interval variation on the definition of uniform distribution mod 1.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks very much in advance.

EDIT: Previously, I had written that $n$ could be fixed. In this case, the answer is obvious, as GH from MO noted. I'm interested in the more complicated case when $n$ varies with $m$. So I edited the question.

Comment: The contribution of the first $n$ terms, divided by $m$, tends to $0$ as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: Let's consider the following generalization: a sequence $x_{n}$ is uniformly distributed mod 1 with respect to a sequence of interval $I_{m}$ with $| I_{m}|$ tending to $\infty$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$, if: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{|I_{n}|}|\lbrace j\in I_{n}, \lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b] \rbrace|=(b-a).$$ Then a generalization of the Weyl's criterion and the Weyl's inequality for exponential sums could suffice to prove that the sequence $\lbrace f(n)\rbrace$ is u.d. mod 1 with respect to the intervals $[m^{3},...,m^{3}+m]$.

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are equivalent. The second property implies the first one upon setting $n:=1$. The first property implies the second one as follows.

Assume the first property. Fix $n\geq 1$, and let $m\to\infty$. Then
\begin{align*}&|\lbrace j=n,...,n+m :\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|=\\
=&|\lbrace j=1,...,n+m :\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|-|\lbrace j=1,...,n-1 :\lbrace x_{j}\rbrace\in [a,b]\rbrace|\\
=&(n+m)(b-a+o(1))+O(1)=m(b-a+o(1))+O(1)=m(b-a+o(1)).\end{align*}
Done.

**P.S.** This is certainly not of research level, but I felt like answering it. Simple questions like this are more suitable at http://math.stackexchange.com/